# Windsor IOC registration for Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, castle

Is there in Castle Windsor IoC registration an equivalent for the When clause in Ninject? I want to use Castle Windsor in Sitecore. When I am in the PageEditor (boolean indicator) I want to use a static list instead of making a call to a backend application.

My solution should be something like:

```
        Component.For<ICartProvider>().ImplementedBy<OscarCartProvider>().DependsOn(Dependency.OnValue(false, StateHelper.InMockState())).LifestyleTransient(),
        Component.For<ICartProvider>().ImplementedBy<MockCartProvider>().DependsOn(Dependency.OnValue(true, StateHelper.InMockState())).LifestyleTransient(),
```

StateHelper.InMockState returns a boolean value which should result in laoding the MockCart provider instead of the OscarCartProvider.

Comment: I take it `PageEditor` is resolved from the container?

Comment: Currently it's a static variable in the Sitecore context.

Comment: PageEditor is a static property on a Sitecore context? It might help us to understand a little more if you could add some code to your question, to provide some visual context to what you'd like to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nearest equivalent to Ninject's `When` would probably be the [`IHandlerSelector` interface](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Handler-Selectors.ashx), which allows you to select a given handler based on some predicate, which in the case of the `IHandlerSelector` is the return value of the `HasOpinionAbout` method.

**[Ayende has an example for how HandlerSelectors can be used on his blog.](http://ayende.com/blog/3633/windsor-ihandlerselector)**

Alternatively, and perhaps simpler since it looks like a static list implementation is always desired to be used with `PageEditor`, you could use [`DependsOn()`](http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=Inline-Dependencies&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) when registering `PageEditor` with the container to register your static list implementation to be used  over your other implementation.

Comment: I have implemented the IHandlerSelector. This works fine! Right now  I have a page editor environment which does not use the back end applciations!